# If I run application , I am suddenly getting this error , what is the problem?

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]

Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel$Stub(error)

Answer (score 0):

Enable multiDex inside defaultConfig, or in specific build

```
 defaultConfig {
    ...

    multiDexEnabled true

}
```

And add the following dependency if you are using androidx

```
dependencies {
def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version'}
```

Or the following support library if you are not using androidx

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

}
```

The detailed information and reference given in the following documentation

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex